# Merging or Joining Two Dataframes on Multiple Columns With Different Dates

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, join, merge

I am trying to combine these two dataframes (df1 and df2):

`gmDate            n        pf       pa
0 2012-10-31      ATL       0         0
1 2012-10-31      BKN       0         0
2 2012-10-31      BOS     107       120
3 2012-10-31      CHA       0         0
4 2012-10-31      CHI       0         0
5 2012-10-31      CLE      94        84
6 2012-10-31      DAL      99        91
7 2012-10-31      DEN       0         0
8 2012-10-31      DET       0         0
9 2012-10-31       GS       0         0`

`gmDate         t   tw  tf  ta   o  ow  of oa
0   2012-10-30  WAS 0   0   0   CLE 1   0   0
1   2012-10-30  BOS 0   0   0   MIA 1   0   0
2   2012-10-30  DAL 1   0   0   LAL 0   0   0
3   2012-10-31  DEN 0   0   0   PHI 1   0   0
4   2012-10-31  IND 1   0   0   TOR 0   0   0
5   2012-10-31  HOU 1   0   0   DET 0   0   0
6   2012-10-31  SAC 0   0   0   CHI 1   0   0
7   2012-10-31  SA  1   0   0   NO  0   0   0
8   2012-10-31  DAL 0   0   0   UTA 1   0   0
9   2012-10-31  GS  1   0   0   PHO 0   0   0`

I need pf and pa in df1 to populate into tf and ta or of and oa in df2 based on matching gmDate and n against t or o in df2.  The df1 includes every day in the calendar, whether or not a team played that day, and df2 contains only the days a team played.  I have not been able to get a merge or join to work for me.

Currently I have been trying to do this by running two separate for loops:

`for s in range(0, len(df1)):
    for d in range(0, len(df2):
        if df1.iloc[s,0] == df2.iloc[d,0] and df1.iloc[s,1] == df2.iloc[d,1]:
            df2.iloc[d,3] = df1.iloc[s,2]
            df2.iloc[d,4] = df1.iloc[s,3]`

and then:

`for s in range(0, len(df1)):
    for d in range(0, len(df2):
        if df1.iloc[s,0] == df2.iloc[d,0] and df1.iloc[s,1] == df2.iloc[d,5]:
            df2.iloc[d,7] = df1.iloc[s,2]
            df2.iloc[d,8] = df1.iloc[s,3]`

Each of them takes a VERY long time to run.  df1 has a length of 29,520 and df2 has a length of 7,379.

Sorry if this is too confusing.  I looking either the best way to do this with a merge/join or not have my loops run forever.

Thank you in advance for your help.

Answer (score 0):

I think I have understood well what you want. My idea is that you can do this:

you want to substitute in the columns `tf` and `ta` of the dataframe `df2` with the columns of the dataframe `df1`, `pf` and `pa` when the dates coincide that is:
(df1 ['gmDate']. values) == (df2 ['gmDate']. values)

There you select the rows and column of `df2`what do you want to replace, doing:

```
df2.loc[(df1['gmDate'].values)==(df2['gmDate'].values),['tf','ta']]
```

what are these:

```
    tf  ta
3   0   0
4   0   0
5   0   0
6   0   0
7   0   0
8   0   0
9   0   0
```

and assign to it:

```
df1.loc[(df1['gmDate'].values)==(df2['gmDate'].values),['pf','pa']].values
```

what are these:

```
array([[ 0,  0],
       [ 0,  0],
       [94, 84],
       [99, 91],
       [ 0,  0],
       [ 0,  0],
       [ 0,  0]])
```

Doing it also in the opposite case you get the code:

```
df2.loc[(df1['gmDate'].values)==(df2['gmDate'].values),['tf','ta']]=df1.loc[(df1['gmDate'].values)==(df2['gmDate'].values),['pf','pa']].values
df2.loc[(df1['gmDate'].values)!=(df2['gmDate'].values),['of','oa']]=df1.loc[(df1['gmDate'].values)!=(df2['gmDate'].values),['pf','pa']].values
```

df2 Output:

```
    gmDate      t   tw  tf  ta  o   ow  of  oa
0   2012-10-30  WAS 0   0   0   CLE 1   0   0
1   2012-10-30  BOS 0   0   0   MIA 1   0   0
2   2012-10-30  DAL 1   0   0   LAL 0   107 120
3   2012-10-31  DEN 0   0   0   PHI 1   0   0
4   2012-10-31  IND 1   0   0   TOR 0   0   0
5   2012-10-31  HOU 1   94  84  DET 0   0   0
6   2012-10-31  SAC 0   99  91  CHI 1   0   0
7   2012-10-31  SA  1   0   0   NO  0   0   0
8   2012-10-31  DAL 0   0   0   UTA 1   0   0
9   2012-10-31  GS  1   0   0   PHO 0   0   0
```

Comment: That is exactly the output I am looking for.  I just do not understand the application of the code you gave me.  I see you have boolean expressions at the front and I am not sure how you are suggesting that I implement this.  Thank you again for your help.

Comment: if you have any question,
do not hesitate to ask!

Comment: I tried running the first line you game me (```df2.loc[(df1['gmDate'].values)==(df2['gmDate'].values),['tf','ta']]```) it returns a False.  If I change the == to a = I get a syntax error that points to the =.

Comment: Also, I need to both date (```gmDate```) and team name (n & t) to match to assign the values to tf and ta.

Comment: With dataframe you show it works, i need one dataframe 
that contains all possible problems that may occur to solve it

Comment: What is the best way for me to share with you what I am working with?  Can you message me directly I will send you my csv's?  I have this set up on a Kaggle notebook.  Should I share it with you?

Comment: I just added you as a collaborator on Kaggle.  Let me know if you do not get it. I am trying to populate teamPtsFor, teamPtsAgnst, opptPtsFor and opptPtsAgnst in the nba_new data frame with ptsFor and ptsAgnst from the nba_stand data frame.  I am either looking for a good merge/join method or to simplify the ```for``` loops I wrote that take hours (seriously hours) to execute. Thank you again for your help.